# android - AsyncTask not reaching onPostExecute() - "The application may be doing too much in its main thread"

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, gson

I have a Fragment in which I want to parse a JSON and create an ArrayList with some of its attributes and then put the ArrayList's data to a Spinner. However, I do not know if I am doing the AsyncTask as it I should. 
Everytime I try a new way to parse the JSON from a URL in my Fragment Activity either the app crashes with "Unfortunately, the app has stopped" message or the Spinner stays empty. I verified with Logs that I never reach the onPostExecute() method on the AsyncTask.
Questions: 
- What am I doing wrong? 
- Should I be using AsyncTask?

My code:

```
 private class LoadResources extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.v(TAG, "pre-execute");
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Log.v(TAG, "background");

            Log.v(TAG, urls[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }

            try {
                URL u = new URL(urls[0]);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
// the above parsing works, I've tested
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement elem = parser.parse(sb.toString());
                JsonArray array = elem.getAsJsonArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                        JsonElement elem1 = array.get(i);
                        JsonArray tmpArr = elem1.getAsJsonArray();
                        for (JsonElement elem2 : tmpArr) {
elem2.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());

                           myArrayList.add(elem2.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("name").toString());
                return urls[0];
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String params) {
Log.v(TAG, params);

            }

        }
```

On the onCreateView:

```
LoadResources loader = new LoadResources();
            loader.execute("http://localhost:5000/avalidpath);

            text = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nomeAluno);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myArrayList);
            text.setAdapter(adapter);

            text.setThreshold(3);
```

Right now the app stops working when I swipe to this fragment.
Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: The JSON parsing should be done in the `doInBackground`. But remember, `AsyncTasks` are supposed to be short threaded tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should do the heavy work in doInBckground method.

onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter. Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

EDIT:

```
class LoadResources extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

     Context context;

     public LoadResources(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
     }

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ...
        return myArrayList;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> params) {
       ((YourActivity)context).setMyAdapter(params);
     }

}
```

In your Activity (fragment or whatever) :

```
public void setMyAdapter(ArrayList<String> params) {
   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myArrayList);
   text.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Edited, thanks. Right now the app doesnt crash, but it doesn't do nothing with the ArrayList

Comment: Thanks, @issathink! I can't call the adapter method from context, tho :/

Comment: Did you try to cast it ? something similar would do the trick `((YourActivity) context).setMyAdapter(params);`

Answer (score 1):

onPostExecute is done on the UI thread.  You have way too much work on it.  Everything that isn't directly effecting a UI element should be done in doInBackground.  Right now your doInBackground is doing nothing.

Comment: Edited, thanks. Right now the app doesnt crash, but it doesn't do nothing with the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Move whole code from `onPostExecute` to `doInBackground`. You can use `publishProgress(...);` and `onProgressUpdate` to add items to list. Or create local list in AsyncTask and addAll items to your global List in `onPostExecute`